# Moving selection menu for terminal in C

Tags: c, ubuntu, terminal

I'm trying to make a menu where you can select different menu points by pressing buttons. Like if you press 'w' the little arrow is moving up and pressing 's' for moving down. Maybe I should also mention that I use Ubuntu and its default terminal for this program.

Here is the code:

```
int printSaveMenu(config_t *config)
{
    char input;
    int position = MOV;
    clrscr();
    printf(" >Quit Game without saving?\n  Save Game!");
    while(1)
    {
        input = getch();
        if(input == 'w'/*config->movement[UP]*/ && position!=UP)
        {
            printf(" ");
            gotoxy0(2,0);
            printf(">");
            position = UP;
        }
        else if(input == 's'/*config->movement[DOWN]*/ && position !=DOWN)
        {
            printf(" ");
            gotoxy0(2,1);
            printf(">");
            position = DOWN;
        }
    }
}
```

And this is the library I'm using for clrscr(); and gotoxy0();: https://ghostbin.com/paste/54oeq

Sorry for the German comments but the library should explaint itself.
Here is the output when pressing 'w' and 's' once:

```
> uit Game without saving?
 Save Game!
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that the cursor moves forward after `printf` finishes. So when you print a space to "erase" the selection arrow, you're actually overwriting the first character in the text. Inserting a second `gotoxy0` call will fix this:

```
...
if(input == 'w'/*config->movement[UP]*/ && position!=UP)
{
    gotoxy0(2,1); // <----
    printf(" ");
    gotoxy0(2,0);
    printf(">");
    position = UP;
}
else if(input == 's'/*config->movement[DOWN]*/ && position !=DOWN)
{
    gotoxy0(2,0); // <----
    printf(" ");
    gotoxy0(2,1);
    printf(">");
    position = DOWN;
}
```